# US Citizen, US Company with UK subisdiary, How to work from UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen and I work for a US company. My company has a subsidiary in the UK where we have at least one person employed.

What are my options for working from London? How long can a "business" trip to the UK last? And how frequently can I do it?

Also, what would be the process of me transferring to the UK subsidiary? I believe there is an easier visa process for an internal company transfer but I'm not sure where to start looking for that.

Thank you!

Comment: There's a [visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/overview) for that!

Comment: Business trip != working. If you get caught working while on business trip (i.e.: doing actual work that you don't need anyone else from the local office physically be present near you to do) you may end up being deported and denied future entry.

You'd be surprised, but most countries have quite similar laws when it comes to illegal immigration, and the UK laws are not all that much different from the US ones.

Comment: If your company have both UK and US locations are intending to transfer you or send you on business from one to another, they ought to be responsible for ensuring you have the correct visa/documentation before sending you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [gov.uk](http://gov.uk/) site is almost always the best place to start when trying to find visa information.

The visa you're probably looking for is the [Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/overview). There are various requirements, including that the employer in the UK is licensed to issue Tier 2 visa sponsorships. The company will need to apply for the [tier 2 licensing scheme](https://www.gov.uk/uk-visa-sponsorship-employers/overview)

You could use the visitor visa for short trips, including for business meetings - but you couldn't work in the country with the visa. Beware: If you use the business visa incorrectly, you may well have other visas denied.